# How to programmatically trigger actions when last Linux terminal is exited/killed?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, automation

I've modified my .bashrc to mount directories when I start first terminal after login.
If mount point still exists when I start new terminal nothing is done.

Now I want to add a bit of code when last linux terminal is closed/exited (e.g. umount those directories, etc..)

Also there is this *not-so-intelligent* way of discovering how many terminal instances are still running:

```
ps -au | grep "bash" | grep "grep" -v -c
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. and I'm using bash shell.

Questions:

1. Is there a file which is "triggered" on terminal exit just like .bashrc is on terminal startup? I've tried messing around with .bash_logout but it doesn't seem to do anything in my case (echo, touch..)
2. Is there another way to do what I'm trying to achieve which doesn't include file from question #1 (if such file even exists)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to modify `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about specific, narrow problems encountered while *writing code*. For questions about system administration, see [unix.se].

Comment: That said, one place you can hook arbitrary session shutdown actions would be [PAM ("Pluggable Authentication Modules")](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam.d).

Comment: Another option is to use [Sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) to get a filtered stream of syscall events one can act on as one chooses; that includes process-exit events.

Comment: Either way -- if you encounter a specific, reproducible problem while trying to use one of those approaches, feel free to ask about it here. If you want help *choosing an approach* (and thus haven't yet encountered any specific problem implementing such an approach), other Stack Exchange-family sites will be better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done with the help of `trap` which is a shell builtin.

For example if you want to clear a folder on running `exit` command in bash >

```sh
trap "rm /cache/*" EXIT
```

The syntax should be like `trap <command> <SIGNAL>`

Just put this in the bottom of `~/.bashrc` with your desired command and it should run before the terminal is killed.

Try `trap --help` to know more.